# Fillable Pdf files cannot be open in browser

Tags: php, apache, pdf

I have serveral pdf files in server. All files successfully opened in browser except the fillable pdfs with editable forms. I got this error messsage from server.

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /file/location...

Answer (score 0):

I myself got solution of this problem. It was actually problem from server. Server doesnt give access to every kind of file format in my case simple pdf and fillable pdf.So when i add this below code in .htacccess. It solved .

```
<FilesMatch "^[^.]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png|pdf|doc|docx|txt|rtf|ppt|pptx|xls|mp4|mov|mp3|mpg|mpeg)$">
```

Satisfy Any
Allow from all